# How to get core dump from process using jvm in docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jvm, ignite, coredump

I have a C++ application using apache ignite libraries running inside a docker container with ubuntu 16.04 base image. I run the program manually from bash shell inside docker container. Somehow it crashes inside my application logic with the following log.

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000004df5c8, pid=132, tid=0x00007f60018c9700

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_242-b08) (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04-b08)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
C  [masterapp+0xdf5c8]

 Core dump written. Default location: /usr/local/bin/core or core.132

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /usr/local/bin/hs_err_pid132.log
[thread 140052484749056 also had an error]


 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Docker file used is

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY files/masterapp /usr/local/bin/
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

In bash shell I did

```
cd /usr/local/bin
./masterapp
```

But no core dump file is found at /usr/local/bin/core in container filesystem. Is there any restriction getting core dumps from ubuntu docker containers?? Or what needs to be done to get it??

Comment: Clarify if you have been searching container's or host's filesystem.

Comment: I was looking inside /usr/local/bin in container file system.

Comment: Have you tried using different current dir? I didn't find any customization for this path with brief search.

Comment: @alamar. tried only with working directory set as /usr/local/bin

Comment: When the application crashes, does the container exit and restart?  The core dump in the (old) container filesystem won’t survive that.

Comment: Agree with David Maze - it would help if you told us more details about how exactly you run the container.

Comment: I have edited the question with Dockerfile and execution method. Also hs_err_pid132.log was there. In /usr/local/bin.